# Android - Google SignIn not working with AWS-Amplify Cognito as expected

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Amplify (Cognito) to SignIn using Google. Once I click Sign-In with Google, it is opening WebView allowing me to enter email and password. Once I submit, I can see there is a record in Cognito User Pool. However, the Web View is not redirecting me back to the App.

So, when I am forcefully closing the WebView, I get an AWS exception saying "User cancelled the Signin process".

I have set the Callback URLs in Google Console, AWS Cognito Pool and in Amplifyconfig file.

Here is the code snippet (MainActivity.java):

Amplify.Auth.signInWithSocialWebUI(AuthProvider.google(), this,

result -> Log.i("AuthQuickstart", result.toString()),
error -> Log.e("AuthQuickstart", error.toString())

@Override

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

 if (requestCode == AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.WEB_UI_SIGN_IN_ACTIVITY_CODE) {

        Amplify.Auth.handleWebUISignInResponse(data);

    }else{

        commonLogin.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }

}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        Log.d("Google ",account.getDisplayName());
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. Did you ever find a solution? One thing I did find is that if, after you've logged in successfully, you refresh the webview (pull to refresh or 3 dots refresh), and you're presented with a stripped down login button, it does work after you press the button.

Comment: One thing to note is that in your question you mention that it's opening a webview -- not actually true -- it's opening an actual browser.

Comment: Another note -- you should not need to do the onActivityResult if you implement the `HostedUIRedirectActivity` in your AndroidManifest.xml as the directions specify. However, see [this thread](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/1514)  to see that you might need to use OnActivityResult anyhow.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada , have you found a solution yet? I'm having the same problem as you except the refresh button doesn't do what you described.

Comment: @confusedstudent I got it to work eventually but it is still flakey. If you clear chrome's data and run it so it goes through the entire process, it's likely to fail the first time as described in my first comment. However, once you refresh the browser (swipe down), it works. [This is the gist](https://gist.github.com/johnnylambada/39f2c0d857cc00bc972ff292c6d71d71) of my login activity if it helps.

Comment: Hey Guys, I am also facing the same problem. Did any of you find the solution for this yet?